# Facebook friends.getLists failing

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying a simple request on Facebook to return all my friend lists.  I'm trying this in Facebook's test console, as well as through an iPhone app i'm working on.

friends.getLists
(also alternatively through FQL)

```
SELECT flid, name FROM friendlist WHERE owner=4810796
```

I am currently logged in, so using that number should be valid.

Both are returning an empty list (not erroring out), but I am certain that I have a few friend lists set up.  I've also tried using this with a test account I set up, but got the same results.  I could have sworn this command was working earlier.

Can anyone please either verify or reject that this is happening for them?

Thanks.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that this is a bug with FQL - if I sit there and click 'Call Method' in the test console, it occasionally returns the correct results, but very sporadically, like 1 in 10.  The other commands are working every time.

Comment: Nevermind - it seems they've resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Makre sure that you have put up everything correctly. **[See this good step-by-step tutorial :)](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Facebook-Programming-API-Friends-P851.html)**

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have everything set up correctly.. I've made friends lists on my facebook account, and other than that, it's just running that command in the test console and seeing if it returns anything.  It isn't.